# Сумма постов категорий с учетом всех вложенных категорий

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Хочу на сайте в разделе вывести подразделы с количеством постов в каждом.

```
Услуги
-- Автоуслуги
---- Автокраны
---- Манипуляторы
-- Коммуникации
---- Водоснабжение
---- Электроснабжение
-- Строительство
---- Фундамент
```

Т.е захожу в раздел Услуги у меня на странице отображаются подразделы

```
Автоуслуги 10
Коммуникации 20
Строительство 30
```

Вчера я использовал MySQL и делал так:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.alias, COUNT(p.id) AS count
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.category_id = c.id
WHERE 
    c.category_id = ?
GROUP BY c.id
```

Но сегодня, я вдруг осознал, что у меня не считаются посты во вложенных категориях. Т.к. разделы могут быть разной вложенностью, потребуется рекурсивный запрос. Почитав в Интернете, я часто встречал упоминание того, что MySQL не поддерживают подобные запросы. И решил перейти на PostgreSQL. Но так как я с ним не знаком, у меня встала проблема с написанием запроса.

Вот что я только написал:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT c.id, c.name, c.alias, 0 AS amount
    FROM categories AS c
    WHERE c.category_id = ?

    UNION

    SELECT c.id, c.name, c.alias, amount + COUNT(p.id) AS amount
    FROM r c
    LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON c.id = p.category_id
)
SELECT * FROM r;
```

Но кажется я сделал не правильно, потому что не вижу перехода на следующий уровень вложенности категорий. Могли бы вы мне помочь с составление правильного запроса?

Comment: Для начала нужно заменить UNION на UNION ALL.

Comment: по хорошему к count полагается group by, только я боюсь вам его не дадут в рекурсии сделать. тогда думаю будет проще просто получить все дерево, рекурсией, а посчитать уже снаружи от with. Кстати в MySQL то же при желании считается, но с тааакими извращениями, что действительно лучше не надо :)

Comment: @Mike если нельзя использовать GROUP BY то как я вызову функцию COUNT ?

Comment: @Mike значит рекурсия мне не поможет.

Comment: Думаю поможет. надо немного подумать ... В крайнем случае count можно получить подзапросом в списке выборки, но это как то совсем скучно

Comment: плохо что вы структуру таблиц не показали. в одном запросе у вас post, в другом services. Да и руками набивать контрольный пример лениво ...

Comment: @Mike я забил и сделал через максимальное кол-во `left join`

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что посты помут быть к любому уровню и нам надо на уровне показать количество постов непосредственно к нему и всем его подуровням ?

Comment: @Mike пример у Авито. Напротив каждой категории указано количество объявлений. И если перейти в подраздел он разделяется на другие подразделы. У меня тоже самое, только посты.

Comment: И у вас в запросе то c.id, то c.parent, то c.category_id сколько же у вас там id в этой таблице. я все таки предположил что только 2 id и parent. Авито не видел. самое главное - если в электроснабщении есть пост он показывается и для Коммуникаций и для Услуг ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем виде как нибудь так:

```
with recursive RCTE as(
  select id as root,id,name,parent
    from categories where parent=1
  union all
  select R.root, C.id, R.name, R.parent
   from RCTE R, categories C
  where C.parent=R.id
)
select root, name, count(p.id)
  from RCTE c
  left join posts p on p.category_id=c.id
 group by root, name
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f0f32/1)

Comment: Спасибо! Ничего себе он длинный. Посмотрим его скорость выполнения.

Comment: на большом объеме скорость не очень будет. он же начинает с того, что берет количества для всех категорий. Возможно стоит сначала получить дерево, а потом к этому дереву подклеить посты уже за пределами рекурсии ... подумаю над этим позже ...

Comment: можно и так, только сумму придется высчитывать с помощью php.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов Да нет, зачем же. сумму просто собирать как и сейчас на самом последнем этапе.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов Знаете, оно так даже короче. поправил. Хотя конечно при больших нагрузках как в авито конечно никто так делать не будет. Они как минимум должны в триггерами на posts сразу обновлять количества, хранящиеся в самих категориях. Ну или кешировать каким нибудь другом способом.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Почему-то я совсем забыл о использовании дополнительной колонки.