# mysql скорость обращения к таблице-ам

Tags: mysql, база-данных, таблицы

Какова разница в более частом обращении к 1 таблице или однократные обращения к нескольким. Есть ли смысл (кроме явного удобства хранения) разделения данных по разным таблицам и как это влияет на скорость.

ЧТО Я ИМЕЮ ВВИДУ:
Допустим обратился за выборкой данных в таблицу "А" за информацией о конкретной записи с алиасом(индекс) "hello-world", запрос дал результат ввиде возврата массива найденой строки таблицы "А" которая оказалась статьей.

Обратился снова к таблице "А" но теперь за алиасом(индекс) "hello-world" скрывается таксономия в которой идет соответствие алиаса к конкретному термину и вот по tid(индекс) пошло обращение к таблице сопоставления "Б", которая возвратила N строк где термин id(индекс) был равен статье id, снова идет поиск в таблице "А" но уже возврат списка всех статей по их id(индекс) соответствующих термину/метке.

П.С
Если вдруг существует таблица сравнения скорости различных операций чтоб правильно формировать запросы, дайте ссылку т.к я пытался что-то подобное найти но не нашел...(возможно это все странные вопросы но я пока что мало сведом в БД) 
Спасибо!

Comment: Таблиц сравнения скоростей нет, нюансов огромное количество. Но общие тенденции таковы, что SQL в принципе позволяет любой разрез данных из любого количества таблиц получить одним единственным запросом. И получение данных единственным запросом быстрее, чем если программе приходится делать несколько. Данные в таблицах же размещаются так, что бы: 1. соответствовать модели данных в реальной жизни и позволять избегать противоречивости. 2. облегчать написание запросов, быстро получающих нужные данные. И обратите внимание: правильные структуры БД для 1 и 2 пунктов могут сильно отличаться ...

Comment: А еще, если предполагается серьезная система и в ней будет действительно много данных, то некоторые вопросы по производительной архитектуре БД решаются только экспериментальным путем. Потому что ни один учебник вам не скажет, что конкретно в MySQL  функция substr примененная к результатам другой функции, для получения из нее первых 300 символов (при том, что их там заведомо не более 50) при операциях group by способна ускорить запрос примерно в 1000 раз, просто ввиду наличия бага при работе с некоторыми типами данных

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что нет большой разницы в кол-ве таблиц, есть только правильно построенный запрос который обойдет их всех? Т.е универсальные методы предлагаемые фреймворками уже могут не подойти. Как тогда лучше, отделять сущности разных типов в разные таблицы или хранить их в одной(но тогда в ней станет больше строк). Т.е сильно ли замедлится поиск по таблице если в нее впихнуть тысячу записей которые могут друг на друга ссылаться если окажутся ссылками типа терминов таксономии?

Comment: таксономия обычно предполагает древовидные структуры. По этой (ну и по другим причинам) вам стоит использовать postgresql. Потому что MySQL практически единственная из распространенных БД, которая не умеет работать с древовидными данными

Comment: Я думал добавить поле родителя для каждого термина и строить древо уже по получению результатов из таблицы... Не знаю насколько это усложнит жизнь но ничего более простого в голову не пришло.

Comment: да, деревья так обычно и строятся. только СУБД отличные от MySQL умеют делать что то вроде такого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769422/194569  т.е. рекурсивно собирать нужные данные

Comment: и да, рекурсивный запрос будет быстрее последовательной выборки отдельными запросами. Но все равно это довольно тяжелая операция. И при большом объеме данных может потребоваться куча ухищрений для оптимизации. Вся суть которых в общем то сводится к "получить все данные по возможности из единственной записи"

Comment: По этому я и хотел либо делать выборку "термин" => "id записи", либо получать все термины. Если термины это отдельная таблица, тогда проще выносить и алиасы в отдельную таблицу "алиас" => "тип сущности" => "id" (тип понадобиться чтобы видеть в какую таблицу за ним идти). Однако если все в одной таблице (кроме сопоставлений, термины как тип сущности такой же как статьи) то бегать между таблицами не придется, единственный вопрос останется в скорости если кол-во записей будет расти (но у меня их фиксированное кол-во). Думаю все же попробовать, если не выйдет перейду на другую СУБД.

Comment: Надо еще учитывать на чем БД лежит. если это жесткий диск, то другая таблица обычно лежит на диске где то в другом месте и при частом обращении то к одной то к другой головкам дальше бегать. В принципе в одной большой таблице проблема примерно та же, желательно что бы данные лежали поближе друг к другу и тут может помочь только правильный выбор первичного ключа. потому что в MySQL (InnoDb) данные физически в таблице лежат в порядке первичного ключа