# Выборка из БД всех потомков древовидной сущности

Tags: база-данных

В СУБД PostgreSQL имеется БД, содержащая таблицу древовидной сущности. Т.е. в записях этой таблицы есть ссылки на другие записи этой таблицы. Визуально эта сущность отображается в виде дерева.

```
root
  item1
    item11
      item111
  item2
    item21
      item211
      item212
        item2121
    item22
```

Уровней вложенности может быть достаточно много. Вопрос: как с помощью SQL запроса выбрать всех потомков конкретной записи? Т.е. для заданного элемента, например, item2 SQL запрос должен возвращать: item21, item211, item212, item2121, item22.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769315/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9/769422#769422

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, ваша задача — классический
случай для использования [рекурсивных
общих табличных выражений](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/queries-with):

```
 name | parent 
------+--------
 1    | NULL
 2    | NULL
 11   | 1
 22   | 2
 111  | 11
 222  | 22
```

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t_2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM t_1 WHERE name = '1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t_1.*
    FROM t_1
    JOIN t_2 ON t_1.parent = t_2.name
)
SELECT *
  FROM t_2
;
```

```
 name | parent 
------+--------
 1    | NULL
 11   | 1
 111  | 11
```

Comment: Не совсем понял. У вас в запросе фигурируют 2 таблицы: t_1 и t_2. В моем случае таблица только одна.

Comment: @krn-prog  Временное отношение `t_2` создаётся внутри запроса, в секции `WITH RECURSIVE`.  Почитайте документацию по ссылке.

Comment: Да, все получилось. Спасибо за ответ и пояснение!

Comment: Пожалуйста, и добро пожаловать в сообщество.  Не забывайте отмечать ответы как верные, нажав галочку слева от ответа.